# Slow SQL performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a query as follows;

```
 SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Table
```

The table contains 33 million records - it contains a primary key on Id and no other indices.

The query takes 30 seconds.

The actual execution plan shows it uses a clustered index scan.

We have analysed the table and found it isn't fragmented using the first query shown in this link: http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Index_Maintenance.

Any ideas as to why this query is so slow and how to fix it.

The Table Definition:

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DbConversation](
[ConversationID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ConversationGroupID] [int] NOT NULL,
[InsideIP] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[OutsideIP] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[ServerPort] [int] NOT NULL,
[BytesOutbound] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[BytesInbound] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[ServerOutside] [bit] NOT NULL,
[LastFlowTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[LastClientPort] [int] NOT NULL,
[Protocol] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
[TypeOfService] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_Conversation_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
[ConversationID] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]
 GO
```

One thing I have noticed is the database is set to grow in 1Mb chunks.

It's a live system so we restricted in what we can play with - any ideas?

UPDATE:

OK - we've improved performance in the actual query of interest by adding new non-clustered indices on appropriate columns so it's not a critical issue anymore.

`SELECT COUNT` is still slow though - tried it with NOLOCK hints - no difference.

We're all thinking it's something to do with the Autogrowth set to 1Mb rather than a larger number, but surprised it has this effect. Can MDF fragmentation on the disk be a possible cause?

Comment: Question 1: do you really need the exact count? Or just an estimate?

Comment: Neither - this is just a query we ran after observing slow performance on something else. We were quite surprised to find it was so slow. Gonna try updating stats, but they're set to autoupdate.

Comment: Can't you just use a constant? I mean, how does the difference between it having 33 million~ or it actually having 33.212.293 records impact you?

Comment: Its a guess, but have you tried playing with different serialization levels? -- It may be costly to do an index scan in SERIALIZABLE or SNAPSHOT.

Comment: As stated - the results of this query are irrelevant - the slow database performance is however a major issue.

Comment: @BonyT - Using a `COUNT` to diagnose slow performance isn't very illuminating.  Can you open a new question with the actual issue and maybe some execution plans and/or IO statistics?

Comment: @BonyT: Exactly as @JNK advises. Post a new question with the actual slow query, the execution plan, the tables structure, indexes, etc.

Comment: Adding NC indexes indicates a better access path onto the table that can be used by COUNT(*)...

Comment: The NC indexes didn't help with the Count

Comment: "we've improved performance in the actual query of interest by adding new non-clustered indices on appropriate columns so it's not a critical issue anymore." -> why ask about COUNT?

Comment: It was our starter for investigating where the issue was. When this was slow we were surprised. Will defrag overnight and report back tomorrow on what the results are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this a frequently read/inserted/updated table?  Is there update/insert activity concurrent with  your select?

My guess is the delay is due to contention.

I'm able to run a count on 189m rows in 17 seconds on my dev server, but there's nothing else hitting that table.

If you aren't too worried about contention or absolute accuracy you can do:

`exec sp_spaceused 'MyTableName'` which will give a count based on meta-data.

If you want a more exact count but don't necessarily care if it reflect concurrent `DELETE` or `INSERT` activity you can do your current query with a `NOLOCK` hint:

`SELECT COUNT(id) FROM MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)` which will not get row-level locks for your query and should run faster.

Comment: Not a very busy database - contention not an issue (statement nearly always takes exact same time to respond 30s and using NOLOCK hint makes no difference.)

Comment: @BonyT - Then you have some other issues.  How wide is this table?  This isn't directly relevant to the `COUNT` but it does affect how many pages SQL needs to pull to get the count, which can matter at higher volumes.  What other perf issues are you having?

Comment: Accepted, although may never know what the actual problem was/is here as on someone elses turf and they have put in place a workaround I understand.

Answer (score 2):

Thoughts:

- Use `SELECT COUNT(*)` which is correct for "how many rows" (as per ANSI SQL). Even if ID is the PK and thus not nullable, SQL Server will count ID. Not rows.
- If you can live with approximate counts, then use sys.dm_db_partition_stats. See my answer here: [Fastest way to count exact number of rows in a very large table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069237/fastest-way-to-count-exact-number-of-rows-in-a-very-large-table/6069288#6069288)
- If you can live with dirty reads use `WITH (NOLOCK)`

Comment: It really doesn't matter as the optimiser effectively uses the same plan whatever you put inside the brackets. Some people are fussy about using "*" though. Whatever this is irrelevant to the issue.

Comment: @BonyT: If you think it's "fussy" I suggest you verify I *am aware* of the [differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1/1221649#1221649) but count(col) may not give the same plan as count(*). Hence my suggestion

Comment: Yes we have - we actually started with * :)

Comment: No - not you fussy - I have had people suggest I don't use "*" before - somewhere someone started a myth that using * is bad. I adjusted my question to not use * to avoid that issue lol

Comment: @BonyT It will use the same plan but will get different results. Aggregation functions in SQL do not include nulls (this is true for COUNT as well)

Comment: It's a primary key - it's not going to be null!

Comment: @BonyT: Well, my linked answer addresses this myth :-) @Mike M: ID is the PK (so NOT NULL). @Both: COUNT(*) is in the ANSI standard. http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt Look for `Scalar expressions   125` and the line just above. It may or may not be optimised of course

Answer (score 1):

```
use [DatabaseName]

select tbl.name, dd.rows from sysindexes dd
inner join sysobjects tbl on dd.id = tbl.id where dd.indid < 2 and tbl.xtype = 'U'

select sum(dd.rows)from sysindexes dd
inner join sysobjects tbl on dd.id = tbl.id where dd.indid < 2 and tbl.xtype = 'U'
```

By using these queries you can fetch all tables' count within 0-5 seconds

use where clause according to your requirement.....

Comment: Reference site is : http://planetofcoders.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-count-all-rows-in-particular.html

Comment: read the post carefully, his concern is not the `select count(id)` rather slow performance of query

Answer (score 0):

Another idea: When the files grow with 1MB parts, it may be fragmented on the file system. You can't see this by SQL, you see it using a disk defragmentation tool.