# How i can get select rows and rows count

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Hi everyone i am try creat pageing for some entity i have function whith signature like
this `public static List<someClass> somePageingFunc(int curentPage,int pageSize,int out maxCount)`
i can't use stored procedur
i am new in sql please tell me what I'm doing wrong

```
string comandStr = "DECLARE @MaxCount int SELECT @MaxCount= Count (*) FROM tbMediaItems"+
                                    " SELECT top(@NumOfRows) * FROM ( SELECT RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ("+
                                    "ORDER BY Artist), * FROM tbMediaItems) AS a WHERE RowNum > (@NumOfRows * (@CurrentPage - 1)) RETURN @MaxCount";
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = comandStr;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@NumOfRows", SqlDbType.Int).Value = pageSize;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CurrentPage", SqlDbType.Int).Value = curentPage;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Result", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = 

ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
try
                {
                    //SqlDataReader reder = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var ss = reader[0];
                        var bb = reader[1];
                    }
                    maxCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@Result"].Value);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
```

I get Exeption Message = A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.
When i remove RETURN @MaxCount all work ok but i am not get MaxCount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RETURN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms174998.aspx) is used within stored procedures to exit and indicate a status at the same time.  You **CANNOT** use it simply within a query batch.

For your use case, I would probably do one of two things:

1. Use two queries in a batch.  You can use reader.NextResult to move between multiple result sets in a batch.
2. Use two independent SqlCommands

A little more complicated, but you can also add an additional column to the result set, e.g.

```
SELECT top(@NumOfRows) B.*, A.TotalRows
FROM (SELECT TotalRows = COUNT(*) FROM tbMediaItems) A
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Artist) ...
```

Although the `COUNT(*)` in here or in your original could be replaced with [this type of query on the sys.partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6069288/573261) table if your table is very large.  It is mostly accurate except for very highly transactional tables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I used first case with reader.NextResult
just it simple

Answer (score 2):

Update your code and use `ParameterDirection.Output` to get return value :

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Result", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = 
ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

to

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Result", SqlDbType.Int).Direction  = 
 ParameterDirection.Output;
```

### Edit 1:

you can create store-procedure as follows:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[procGetMaxCount]
@NumOfRows int,
@CurrentPage int,
@Result int OUTPUT  
AS    
BEGIN   
    SELECT @Result= Count (*) FROM tbMediaItems
                      SELECT top(@NumOfRows) * FROM ( SELECT RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Artist), * FROM tbMediaItems) AS a WHERE RowNum > (@NumOfRows * (@CurrentPage - 1))                                       
END
```

and update your .cs file as :

```
 string comandStr="procGetMaxCount";
```

and `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately i get  same Exception

Comment: cant you convert your `select` statement as a store procedure

Comment: exactly,but when i remove Return MaxCount from query string

Comment: Thanks but i cant use Stored procedur

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28013/discussion-between-arshad-and-haikmnatsakanyan)