# Is there any way to calculate total number of rows that return from dynamic query in Common Table Expression(CTE) or Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We are in the process of optimizing our database.We have most of store procedure that uses CTE   because it gives us high performance according to our table strucure.We have almost dynamic query that have different result according to different condition.We hold all data in CTE, and check condition, that was the not problem but we need total number of rows that return by each query ,in calculating this it takes lots of time.Temporary table or table variable not suitable in our case as it takes lots of time to insert data in it.We have structure as following

```
With t(fields) as
(select field1,field2.......
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by some column) as row...
from some table and lots of 
inner n left joins 
where some condition ),
rowTotal(RowTotal) as
  (select max(row) from t) 
   select * from t,RowTotal 
   where condition for paging
```

But max(row) took lots of times if i remove this it return data within 100ms. I tried Coun(*),Count(SomeField) and many other it works but took lots of time.How can i achieve total number of rows from cte within some ms any aggregate function will not work for me.Is there any other way to calculate rowtotal like @@rowcount.Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Cant you cant them on the receiving end of the data, in the application?

Comment: I tried all possible solution it works but tooks lots of time whether i calculate total number of record on the end or inside recursive CTE.

Comment: I have solved such problems by reorganizing query - CTE with paging is  designed to return only required unique fields AND total rows count; other tables (left joins  without 1-N relations) are joined later. This is not always doable, depends heavily on query structure. Alternative is not to use total rows (pages) count at all (users do not like that) or to use approximate total (users often do not notice that), like services like google do.

Comment: Did you try to include a `count(*) over() as total_count` in the first CTE?

Comment: @Arvo,Is it is the problem joins i think no without calculating total number of rows it run so fast just around 60ms and i have half millions of data on table.i ask such question previously but did not find right solution.Here is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693683/how-to-calculate-rowtotal-of-cte-that-run-in-less-time. Yes @ a_horse_with_no_name i tried all but did not get what i want.

Comment: For start - can you find count of rows quickly without using CTE? If your CTE is recursive, then probably not. If CTE is not recursive (or even if it recursive, but doesn't create more than single row at deeper levels), then you should be able create simple query to find requierd rows count and then you can optimize it. It is not possible for CTE to find *all* rows faster than single  query does - and for total count it needs just do that.

Comment: How many rows does the query return (and whats the total count)?

Comment: Presently i have Five hundred thousnads but it may be millions and i have to extract only some data about 5o rows on a time to display at front end.

Answer (score 1):

If you are after the total number of rows from the inner query you can add this as a column to your select using `COUNT()` and `PARTITION BY()`.

```
With t(fields) as
(select COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) AS TotalRows,
        field1,field2.......
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by some column) as row...
from some table ...
```

This should give you a count of the total rows in 't' as the first column of `t`

I don't know that this is the fastest way to get the result you want but it works for me on 000's of returned records and prevents extra select queries to find the count separately.