# Check if table exist in spring boot with JPA+Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to create a custom repository in spring boot using JPA + Hibernate. I am new to JPA and Hibernate, so till now I managed to create a table in the DB and push some data to it.

I would like to know if a table exist before creating it or number of rows in a table but I am not able to find any material on it.

Following is the class to create table

```
package repository;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class CustomRepository {

    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TestPersistence");

    public void createTable(String tableName) {
        EntityTransaction txn = null;
        try {
            EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            txn = entityManager.getTransaction();
            txn.begin();

            entityManager.createNativeQuery("CREATE TABLE " + tableName + " (PersonID int, LastName varchar(255))")
                    .executeUpdate();
            txn.commit();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            if (txn != null && txn.isActive()) {
                txn.rollback();
            }
            throw e;
        }
    }

}
```

---

I tried

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'";
```

or

```
String sqlQuery = "SELECT TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROWS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES"
```

With `entityManager.createQuery(sqlQuery).getResultList();` as well but they are giving error.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this would be helpful.

Comment: Hibernate is not a great tool for this task. If you are looking for schema management, take a look at Flyway.

Comment: another option for schema management is [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/)

Comment: The two queries you describe in the `sqlQuery` string are native, so you have to call `createNativeQuery` instead of `createQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by hibernate hbm2ddl function. You can set it to `validate` and on startup hibernate will check if the schema generated matches one in database. [What are the possible values of the Hibernate hbm2ddl.auto configuration and what do they do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/what-are-the-possible-values-of-the-hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-configuration-and-wha)
If you want to check how many rows are in given table you would need to perform count in select statemant like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName`. Something like here [SQL count rows in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916917/sql-count-rows-in-a-table)