# SQL Server - Number of records from all specific columns at sys.tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find out the number of records from all the columns at sys.tables that start with a specific letter.

At the moment I have something like this:

```
SELECT      c.name  AS 'ColumnName'
            ,t.name AS 'TableName'
FROM        sys.columns c JOIN sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE 'u%'
ORDER BY    TableName
            ,ColumnName;
```

Is there a way I can add the number of column records to this?

Tks,
Miguel

Comment: What do you mean by "column records"? "Record" isn't a *thing* is SQL Server. What are you defining a record as?

Comment: Number of rows it is.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` maybe?

Comment: You can get the (estimated) number of rows a table has using the sys objects as well, @MiguelLourenço . A column can't have more (or less) rows that the table does, as *every* column in a row has a value. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28917736/2029983)

Comment: Can you show us an illustration of what you mean? describe for example a database with 3 tables and several columns in each table, and present what is the output which you want to get according to the sample database.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
SELECT      c.name  AS 'ColumnName'
            ,t.name AS 'TableName',
            count(*) AS num
                        
FROM        sys.columns c JOIN sys.tables  t   ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE       c.name LIKE 'u%'
GROUP BY    c.name, t.name
ORDER BY    TableName
            ,ColumnName;
```

Comment: That's always going to return 1 though... Unless you have tables with the same name and columns on different schemas on the same database.

Comment: Do not use single quote for aliasses. Single quote are for strings values