# Show members count

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a question. I want to show the number of registered user on my site.

i already tried to make this query:

```
select count(*) from members
```

and then show the result of the count. but for big table.. it's not good idea i think

but i think it's not optimize..  when i do an explain, the query reads all rows... i suppose that's normal to counts the numbers of members

But is there a best way to do it for performance and optimization?
Thanks a lot

Comment: For most database engines, selecting the count of a table is instantaneous. It doesn't actually count how many rows there are. It has an internal row count for every table and just spits that value out.

Comment: It's optimized for MyISAM, but not for InnoDB.

Comment: COUNT(*) is the fastest. possible, equal to count(1)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069237/fastest-way-to-count-exact-number-of-rows-in-a-very-large-table

Comment: ok perfect! Thanks a lot ! I didnt see that post!