# SQL Sever getting total count from view

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I'm Currently using SQL Server 2008 R2 and ASP.Net with Linq

On Server 1

We have database with a table that contains address info for about a million records.

On Server 2

I have a customer table with about 1/2 million records which contains an AddressID

I have created a **synonym** to link to Server 1 for the address table.  And have created a view to link both tables together within Server 2.

A stored procedure to handle paging of the data so that it returns me a page of 20 records, also tried adding RowNumber into the actual view which made no speed improvements

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCustomerAddressesByPage] 
(
    @pageIndex int,
    @pageSize int,
    @totalRows int output
)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @startRowIndex int
  DECLARE @endRowIndex int

  SET @startRowIndex = (@pageIndex * @pageSize) + 1;
  SET @endRowIndex = (@pageIndex + 1) * @pageSize;

  --SELECT * FROM
  --  (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerID) AS RowNumber,*
  --     FROM View_CustomersAddress) xx
  --WHERE RowNumber >= @startRowIndex AND RowNumber <= @endRowIndex

  SELECT *
    FROM View_CustomersAddress
    WHERE RowNum >= @startRowIndex AND RowNum <= @endRowIndex

  SELECT @totalRows = COUNT(*) FROM View_CustomersAddress  
END
```

This returns me the data within 2 seconds, but to handle the number of pages I also need the total rows and the following bit of code is taking another 20 or so seconds to complete

```
SELECT @totalRows = COUNT(CustomerID) FROM View_CustomersAddress
```

Server code is as follows to populate the data within a gridview

```
public IQueryable<GetCustomerAddressLinesByPageResult2> GetAddress(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows)
{
    var data = dbContext.GetCustomerAddressLinesByPage(startRowIndex, maximumRows);
    return data;
}
```

The view doesn't contain any indexing as you can't due to using a synonym, so I'm currently storing the total rows in a viewstate in my asp.net program so on initial load it takes 25 seconds+ but paging is fine.

Is there anyway to increase the performance of the count() or maybe another way of doing it without using count() which I've not thought of.

**Just to clarify**

Address table on Server 1 has a primary key AddressID and is unique

Customer table on Server 2 has a primary key CustomerID and is unique

The View_CustomersAddress does not have any index due to the synonym between Server 1 and Server 2

Comment: What is index on CustomerId in underlying table? Also do you really want count(customerid) or count(distinct customerid) or customerId is unique in this table?

Comment: Sorry,CustomerID is the primary key and is unique

Comment: take a look at his post. Perhaps it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/6069288/3877877

Comment: I tried using **sys.dm_db_partition_stats** before but that only works on a table, and not a view

Comment: This will not help you but I would like to know why you do count(CustomerID) and not just Count(1) or Count(*) ?

Comment: No reason really, they all seem to return the same timed result

Comment: Can you post the execution plan xml here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're always going to have a problem when you need to display "Total Rows".  In order to do that, it **must** do the full amount of work, the only savings is in the amount of data that is transferred.

If you **must** get a count of "Total Rows" **and** page the data I suggest doing it in two different steps:

## Step 1 - Get Total Rows

`SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Customer`

Notice that I didn't join on the synonym which is part of your slowdown.

## Step 2 - Get Pages Results

(you already know how to do this step)

Comment: This works for my initial problem and I've marked it as answered, but later I'm going to be adding searching capabilities so would need to search across both tables.