# How to pass table name as parameter in select statement in SQL Sever

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, count

Table:

```
Col 
------
Table1 
table2 
table3
```

Query:

```
select count(*) 
from @tablename
```

I wanted to pass `table1`, `table2`, `table3` as parameters for `@tablename` in the select query and get the count for each table

Desired output:

```
 2 (table 1 count)  3 (table 2 count)  4 (table 3 count)
```

Comment: If you want to parametrize a table name, you need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: You want your output in all one row, or is that the result of someone else's edit?

Comment: For row counts this may be okay but if there's any other "common" querying against these tables, this may be a sign of a broken data model. If you're doing "common" querying, it's likely that they should in fact be a single table, and also likely that something that should be modelled as *data* has instead ended up as (less queryable) *metadata*, such as being embedded in the table *name*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use dynamic sql and a cursor to run through them:

Create temp table for testing:

```
DECLARE @tablenametable TABLE(tablename VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tablenametable
VALUES('table1'), ('table2'), ('table3');
```

Use a cursor to run through all tablenames in the table

```
DECLARE @tablename VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE dbcursor CURSOR
FOR
    SELECT tablename
    FROM @tablenametable;
OPEN dbcursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM dbcursor INTO @tablename;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);
        SET @sql = 'select count(*) from '+@tablename;
        PRINT(@sql);
        FETCH NEXT FROM dbcursor INTO @tablename;
    END;
CLOSE dbcursor;
DEALLOCATE dbcursor;
```

Give the following results:

```
select count(*) from table1
select count(*) from table2
select count(*) from table3
```

Just change `PRINT(@SQL)` to `EXEC(@SQL)` when your happy with it

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic sql query.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);

select @sql = stuff((
    select ' union all '
    + 'select cast(count(*) as varchar(100)) 
    + ' + char(39) + '(' + [Col] +' Count)' + char(39) 
    + ' as [table_counts] '
    + ' from ' + [col]
    from [your_table_name]
    for xml path('')
  )
  , 1, 11, ''
);

exec(@sql);
```

### **[`Find a demo here`](http://rextester.com/ZMPN80001)**

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here, you have to use dynamic SQL.

First approach is where you specify table name yourself:

```
declare @tablename varchar(30), @SQL varchar(30)
set @tablename = 'Table1' --here you specify the name
set @SQL = concat('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ', @tablename) --here you build the query

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Second approach lets you use table with names of tables:

```
declare @SQL varchar(8000)
set @SQL = ''
declare @TableNames table(name varchar(30))
insert into @TableNames values ('Table1'), ('Table2'), ('Table3')
--here you build the query
select @SQL = @SQL + ' SELECT ''' + name + ''' AS [TableName], COUNT(*) AS [Count] FROM ' + name + ' UNION ALL' from @TableNames
-- get rid of last "UNION ALL"
set @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, LEN(@SQL) - 10)
--execute the query
EXEC(@SQL)
```

The result of it will be:

```
TableName    Count
Table1       3
Table2       6
Table3       4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys.dm_db_partition_stats` like this <sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6069288/4519059)</sup>:

```
select
    t.col tableName, sum(s.row_count) tableCount
from 
    yourTable t
join
    sys.dm_db_partition_stats s
  on
    (object_name(s.object_id) = t.col )
 and 
    (s.index_id < 2)
group by 
    t.col;
```

[[1]. Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6069288/4519059)

---

One line output version will be:

```
select
    sum(s.row_count), ' ('+t.col +' count) '
from 
    yourTable t
join
    sys.dm_db_partition_stats s
  on
    (object_name(s.object_id) = t.col )
 and 
    (s.index_id < 2)
group by 
    t.col
for xml path('');
```

output:

```
2 (Table1 count) 3 (table2 count) 4 (table3 count)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to avoid sql injection, may be you can simply validate the tableName before sending it to the server, for example let table can contains only latin letters and numbers:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(tableName, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"))
    throw new ArgumentException("tableName");
// now safe use it in sql query:
ExecuteSql("SELECT * FROM " + tableName);
```