# How to get the number of rows in a SQL temporary table without using COUNT(*)

Tags: sql, sql-server

A few efficient methods were shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49695317/13752527) and copied below but that doesn't work for temporary tables.
I really want to avoiding COUNT(*) due to the table size.

The first one below returns and error and the second NULL

```
SELECT CONVERT(bigint, rows) 
FROM sysindexes 
WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(#temporaryTable) 
AND indid < 2 

SELECT SUM (row_count) 
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats 
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID(#temporaryTable)    
AND (index_id=0 or index_id=1);
```

Comment: The second one should work as long as you qualify the DB in all cases -- `select ... from tempdb.sys.dm_db_partition_stats where object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temporaryTable')` (disclaimer: untested, I have no live instance atm).

Comment: It still return NULL when fully qualified and using a SELECT *

Comment: @XavU.  I bet you're running Jeroen's code in another tab.  I think `object_id()` won't properly identify #temporaryTable in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you've got to query tempdb, not whatever current database you're in.  I filtered the specific table by joining to `sysobjects`.  When doing that, you have to know that #temporaryTable is actually not really named that, but just starts with that name.

```
select      o.name,
            rows = CONVERT(bigint, rows) 
from        tempdb..sysindexes i
join        tempdb..sysobjects o on i.id = o.id
where       o.name like '#temporaryTable_%' 
and         indid < 2 

select      o.name,
            row_count = sum(ps.row_count)
from        tempdb.sys.dm_db_partition_stats ps
join        tempdb..sysobjects o on ps.object_id = o.id
where       o.name like '#temporaryTable_%' 
and         (index_id=0 or index_id=1)
group by    o.name
```

Comment: Different sessions can have their own `#temporaryTable` instances, and partially matching on name means you can get multiple results with no way to know which is which. Using `OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temporaryTable')` will only work in the session that created the table, but with the benefit that it will actually get the table created in that session. Which of these approaches is to be preferred depends on what you're after, of course, which the question doesn't make clear.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, that's good to know. I'll make changes to make sure the table works in that session.

Answer (score 0):

If your main goal is to find the total number of rows, you can perhaps run this:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
```

This returns the last id that was logged and thus will be the number of rows (given that id is incrementing serially).

Comment: Thanks Parashar. It returns the name of the table

Answer (score 0):

If the total number of rows is your primary goal

```
SELECT IDENTITY(INT,1,1) AS ID, FirstName,Surname  INTO NewTable FROM ExistingTable;

select max(ID) from NewTable;
```

Note: When another column inherits the identity property, this does not work.